# The conversion of the varchar value '5035899999' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select Distinct
          E.EmpNo,
          convert(date,R.APPLYDATE) AS DateWorked,
      R.PAYCODENAME
From 
TableExportEmployees E
INNER JOIN VP_RTIMEDTLTOTALS R
ON R.PERSONNUM = E.EmpNo
Inner Join VP_SCHEDULE V
ON V.PERSONNUM = E.EmpNo
```

When I am executing this I am getting this error

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The conversion of the varchar value
>   '5035899999' overflowed an int column.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: What are the datatypes and lengths of the columns?

Comment: I am, using SQL Server

Comment: Which column has that value? Is the conversion implicit?

Comment: I'm guessing personnum and empno are not the same datatype. One is `INT`and the other is `VARCHAR`. INT has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 which 5035899999 exceeds. You haven't told us what the datatypes are but the solution is you need to convert whichever is an `INT` to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: ...or fix the columns so they're both `bigint`.

Comment: PERSONNUM is (varchar,not null) , E.EmpNo is (int,not null), APPLYDATE is (datetime,null) and Paycodename is (Varchar,null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make joins, you need to ensure that type of the columns used in the join haves the same type in the two tables.
It may cause these kind of errors.

Verify and tell us what are the column types of:
 - R.PERSONNUM 
 - E.EmpNo
 - V.PERSONNUM

If you are using a int column, you should alter it, using bigint or numeric

Comment: PERSONNUM is (varchar,not null) , E.EmpNo is (int,not null), APPLYDATE is (datetime,null) and Paycodename is (Varchar,null)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in the error code.  It is trying to evaluate that value as type int.

The value is beyond the range supported by int.

See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

Find the violating column, and if you do need to store that large value as a number you'll need to redefine the column to be of type bigint.  Or if it is ok to store as string redefine your column to be of type varchar(greater than 10) since your value is already 10 digits long.

Based on your comment, the violating column is actually PersonNum.  SQL is trying to convert it to int to compare to the EmployeeNum.  To fix it, you need to redefine EmployeeNum to be the same datatype as PersonNum, or redefine them both to be bigint.